# Linux system variables in node

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, bash

I have `NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-production}` in starting script of app.

What does it mean `:-production`?

Also why adding system variable and reading it returns `undefined`? To mitagate it I always have to use `NODE_ENV=production npm start` even if `printenv` shows it

Comment: It would be helpful to answer your last question if you posted more of the startup script.

Answer (score 2):

That's shell syntax; it has nothing to do with Node. It means that if the shell variable `NODE_ENV` (which may be present from the environment) is set to a non-null value, then use that value; otherwise use `production`.

Without seeing the startup script, it's hard to say why it doesn't work, but note that just setting a shell variable in a script does not put that variable into the environment. In Bash, a command line can have a prefix to set up environment variables for that command invocation only, and that's what you're doing with

```
NODE_ENV=production npm start
```

If you want the script to ensure that `NODE_ENV` is exported to the environment, it should look like

```
export NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-production}
```